# Highlight the log while hovering over points in dash plotly

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I have created a graph using dash. i am showing the logs corresponding to the xaxis range, ie. i am displaying the logs from one end of xaxis to the other end.[image]

[image]

Now i want to add a feature like if anyone hover any points on graph, corresponding log get highlighted.
I tried many times but i failed each time.i am new in dash.

Thank you very much for your help.

Regards